# Snubber circuit for SPI clock and SPI MOSI

Tags: snubber

I am using the SPI interface to communicate with the MEMS sensor ([ASM330LHH](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/asm330lhh.pdf)). My plan is to operate it at a 10 MHz speed.

The PCB is split into two parts, connected by cables. The distance between the processor board (TMS5703137CGWTQEP) and the sensor board is 2 inches.

Now, I have a question: How do I calculate the proper size resistor and capacitor for a snubber circuit for the clock and MOSI lines after the cable?”

Comment: Are you concerned about signal reflections on such a set-up?

Comment: @Colin it says on page 1 of the DS this: **SPI & I²C host serial interface**

Comment: The sensor has SPI interface. I will be using cable between sensor and processor board. Cables have high capacitance and may have additional impairments from the connectors.  A snubber termination will probably be needed after the cable.

Comment: Over 2 inches? I don't think so.

Comment: @Colin It does have SPI. And many chips simply tell users to connect to a bus. They don't explicitly say users to connect to a bus which has been damped with snubber if it was ringing.

Comment: Please have a look at this link from TI forum where they had mentioned to have snubber circuit for spi lines (https://e2e.ti.com/support/processors-group/processors/f/processors-forum/332251/spi-clock-and-data-lines-routing-distribution-to-multiple-slaves)

Comment: @Priya That TI discussion is over an exotic application with over 50 distributed SPI nodes that require a complex fan out. You have 1 device 2 inches away.